# Select all text of TextField in Jetpack Compose with mvvm pattern

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In the previous text field, when focused, there was a method in which all letters were selected. I found a way to make it remembered on the screen, but I wonder how to do it on the mvvm pattern.

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(text: String, viewModel: HomeViewModel) {
    val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    val state = viewModel.mainState.text.collectAsState()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = state.value,
            color = Color.Blue,
            fontSize = 40.sp
        )

        Button(
            onClick = { viewModel.mainState.text.value = "New text" },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Green
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)

        ) {
            Text(text)
        }

        TextField(
            value = textState.value,
            onValueChange = { textState.value = it },
            label = { Text("Input text") }
        )

    }
}
```

The code above is from screen to remeber.
But I understand that remember is only declared within @Composable.
The view model does not declare @Composable, so I want to know how to do it in the mvvm pattern.

Below is my code.

**LoginScreen**

```
    val text = viewModel.user_id.value
    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = barcode,
                        onValueChange = {
                            viewModel.changeBarcode(it)
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(all = 4.dp)
                            .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                                if (focusState.isFocused) {
                                    //monitor value

                                }
                            },
                        label = { Text(text = "Barcode") },
                        singleLine = true,
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                        ),
                        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                            onDone = {
                                keyboardController?.hide()
                                viewModel.onTriggerEvent(MenuStateEvent.ScanEvent)
                            }
                        )
                    )
```

**LoginViewModel**

```
val user_id: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("")
```

How change it to mvvm pattern?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. Selecting all the text isn't some state related. Saving the value of the TextField is however state related. Also, your sample shows user_id. What does that have to do with selecting the text? You need to clean up your post and make it easier to understand.

Comment: Could you take a look if this answer helps you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244362/select-all-text-of-textfield-in-jetpack-compose/68245465#68245465

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will be the method you need.

in ViewModel：

```
val user_id = mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
```

in Compose：

```
    TextField(
        value = viewModel.user_id.value,
        onValueChange = { viewModel.user_id.value = it },
        label = { Text("Input text") }
    )
```

Just change the mutableStateOf in ViewModel from "String" to "TextFieldValue(String)" to access it.