# Compose - TextField - SelectAllOnFocus

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

If we want our TextField to have an equivalent behaviour to `EditText:selectAllOnFocus = "true"` we can do something like create a TextFieldValue and set the selection from zero to lenght like `TextRange(0, text.length)`

This works and when user focus the TextField the whole text get selected, the problem is that when we create a TextFieldValue we need to set selection, the default value is Zero.

If the user wants to drag the cursor he just cant. Is there a way for now to create a selectAllOnFocus behaviour that allows the user to drag the cursor all over the text if he wants to in compose?

Comment: Is this what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244362/select-all-text-of-textfield-in-jetpack-compose

Comment: I've tried this, this way you cant drag cursor on TextField....

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "drag cursor". Once the cursor is visible, you can drag it wherever you want.

Comment: you cant, i think that it recompose with textFieldValue and reset the cursor position, not sure about that

Comment: Do you want an editable selection? so you can drag the two point and copy, cut etc

Comment: I can try to set it and see if it fits the behaviour that I expect...do you know a place where I can see how to implement it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think one way is to follow the result selection coming from the TextField onValueChange callback:

```
var editableText by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("some text") }
val textRangeStart = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
val textRangeEnd = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
val textField = remember(editableText, textRangeEnd.value, textRangeStart.value) {
    mutableStateOf(
        TextFieldValue(
            text = editableText ?: "",
            selection = TextRange(textRangeStart.value, textRangeEnd.value)
        )
    )
}
TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        value = textField.value,
        placeholder = { Text("") },
        onValueChange = {
            textEditorViewModel.editableText.value = it.text
            textRangeStart.value = it.selection.start
            textRangeEnd.value = it.selection.end
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: it worked, in the end I just need to keep track of textRangeStart and textRangeEnd to allow user to drag cursor around, thanks!

Comment: @IvanRegados yes, that is the trick