# How to select all on focus in BasicTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying make `BasicTextField` select all contents when user taps on it.

This happens automatically if user will long press on the contents of `BasicTextField` but I want it happening without the long press.
There's a thread [Select all text of TextField in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244362/select-all-text-of-textfield-in-jetpack-compose) but it utilizes `TextFieldValue` object which is hidden in `BasicTextField` but can be passed in `TextField` composable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `TextFieldValue` also with a `BasicTextField`.

Instead of using the `onFocusChanged` modifier you can use the `interactionSource` and change the selection range depending on it.

Something like:

```
var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("Custom text")) }
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isFocused by interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()

LaunchedEffect(isFocused) {

    val endRange = if (isFocused) textFieldValue.text.length else 0

    textFieldValue = textFieldValue.copy(
        selection = TextRange(
                start = 0,
                end = endRange
            )
    )
}

BasicTextField(
    value = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = { textFieldValue = it },
    interactionSource = interactionSource
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the overload because of the onValueChange